# NetSuite sum formula that replaces NULL values with '0.00'

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am looking for help writing a formula for a custom field to show the sum of the calculated values of two other custom currency fields (A & B) in NetSuite. I can do this simply enough using {A}+{B}. However, if either A or B is a null value, then the formula returns nothing. My latest attempt to solve this (see below) didn't work due to "ERROR: Invalid Expression". Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

(CASE WHEN {A} IS NULL THEN '0.00' ELSE {A} END)+(CASE WHEN {B} IS NULL THEN '0.00' ELSE {B} END)

Comment: Try `COALESCE( A, 0 ) + COALESCE( B, 0 ) AS summedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/83149/kw/replace%20null

NVL({A}, 0) + NVL({B}, 0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).